# How to delete file in folder

Tags: c#

I am uploading file before that I want to delete existing file.

```
string newfilename = txtname.Text + "Resume" + fileExtension;
System.IO.File.Delete(newfilename);                 
AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/tmp/jobres/" + uId) + "\\" + newfilename;
```

If I upload a .doc file, after that upload a .pdf file then both are there. I want only latest uploaded file not old file. How I can delete old file?

Comment: You have to save latest updated file name somewhere (so that you can get it back and use to delete) or you can simply delete **all files** (clear folder) prior to downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before upload saveas, you can take file path for the directory and then delete all the existing files and then upload the latest file.

You can reference below code:

```
string newfilename = txtname.Text + "Resume" + fileExtension;
string[] pathOfFiles =  System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/tmp/jobres/" + uId));

foreach (string filePath in pathOfFiles)
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
}

AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/tmp/jobres/" + uId) + "\\" + newfilename;
```